# Count how many times a string appears in pandas df with one variable element

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas df that contains text in one column:

```
df(print):

Country 1 - Name of Country
paragraph text
Country 2 - Name of Country
paragraph text
Country 3 - Name of Country
paragraph text
Country 4 - Name of Country
paragraph text
```

I am trying to count how many times the string "Country # -" appears. The thing is that the number in the middle is something that can change. There could be up to 20 countries listed.

with this example i am hoping to get that:

```
print(count):
4
```

There is an off chance that the word "Country" appears at the start of the paragraph text which is why i was hoping to be able to search for the full "Country + "Number" + "-" string

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks very much!

Comment: This is a clear need for a regex (regular expression).
Any tutorial on the subject will give enough to solve your problem.  You want `[start of line]"Country "[digit]`, which gives you two regex notations to learn.

Comment: Post a visual of ur expected output

Comment: Thank you both. Have just updated and expected output and will look into regex now thanks @Prune

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression on the column that stores the data, for example:

```
np.random.seed(10)
countries_sample = ['Country 1 - text text', 'not Country string', 'Country 2']
df =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(countries_sample,10),
                   columns = ['text_to_validate'])

df.head(3)

#    text_to_validate
# 0 not Country string
# 1 not Country string
# 2 Country 1 - text text
```

The use `str` attribute followed by `contains` method and the regular expression:

```
total = df['text_to_validate'].str.contains('^Country [0-9]+ -', regex=True).sum()
print(total)  # 4
```